# XSLT transformation (help on syntax)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file I would like to use XSLT to transform into a csv file: (revised)

```
<ns4:transaction xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/Ops" xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/Transaction" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/vehicleDetail">
<sender>sending person</sender>
<receiver>receiving person</receiver>
<created>2016-12-31T00:00:00Z</created>
<messages>
    <ns3:vehicleDetail>
        <identifier>
            <vehicle>Benz</vehicle>
            <dayOfOrigin>2016-02-01</dayOfOrigin>
            <localDayOfOrigin>2016-02-01</localDayOfOrigin>
            <initialDayOfOrigin>2016-02-01</initialDayOfOrigin>
            <localInitialDayOfOrigin>2016-02-01</localInitialDayOfOrigin>
        </identifier>
        <vehicleModified>UPD</vehicleModified>
        <vehicleOperStatus>O</vehicleOperStatus>
        <trip modified="UPD">
            <tripNo>198866</tripNo>
        </trip>
        <trip modified="UPD">
            <tripNo>198865</tripNo>
         </trip>
    </ns3:vehicleDetail>
</messages>
</ns4:transaction>
```

My xslt looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/Ops" xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/Transaction" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/vehicleDetail">
<xsl:template match="ns4:transaction">
    <xsl:for-each select="messages/ns3:vehicleDetail/trip">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../../created" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="tripNo"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The CSV file output should look something to this:

```
2016-12-31T00:00:00Z,198866
2016-12-31T00:00:00Z,198865
```

I did try to figure this out using XSLT with generic namespace handling, but I didn't go very far.  Are there any hints/tips on how to do so?

*updated to reflect closer to question.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is about. What do you mean by "generic namespace handling"? The input that you show us uses a prefix without binding it to a namespace - that's not allowed in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a **well-formed** input XML such as:

```
<zero xmlns:alpha="http://example.com/alpha">
    <one>
        <fruit>
            <apple>Red</apple>
        </fruit>
        <alpha:test>
            <alphaA>1</alphaA>
            <alphaB>2</alphaB>
        </alpha:test>
        <alpha:test>
            <alphaA>3</alphaA>
            <alphaB>4</alphaB>
        </alpha:test>
    </one>
    <one>
        <fruit>
            <apple>Blue</apple>
        </fruit>
        <alpha:test>
            <alphaA>5</alphaA>
            <alphaB>6</alphaB>
        </alpha:test>
        <alpha:test>
            <alphaA>7</alphaA>
            <alphaB>8</alphaB>
        </alpha:test>
    </one>
</zero>
```

this would be rather trivial:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/alpha">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/zero">
    <xsl:for-each select="one/ns1:test">
        <xsl:value-of select="../fruit/apple"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

To handle your revised input, your stylesheet should look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/Transaction" 
xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/vehicleDetail">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="ns4:transaction">
    <xsl:for-each select="messages/ns3:vehicleDetail/trip">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../../created" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="tripNo"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note the added `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` declaration (without it a stylesheet is not a stylesheet) and the setting of the output method to text.

Comment: much appreciated.  I was stuck at figuring out how to select the value of the xml tag which is the parent of the for-each loop.  this actually helped in figuring that part out.

Comment: However, I do have a question.  If the tags in the non-well-formed xml does contain colons (i.e. <ns1:transaction><a>blablabla</a></ns1:transaction>) I can't just use match="ns1:transaction".  Is there any other way to capture the XML nodes below the namespaced tag, in this case, blablabla in <a></a>?

Comment: @kazuni If your input is not well-formed XML, it will not be processed by XSLT. OTOH, if the prefix **is** bound to a namespace, you need to declare the same namespace in your stylesheet and assign it a prefix (the same one or another, it doesn't matter). Then you can use that prefix to select elements in the source XML.

Comment: I have no problem declaring the same namespace in the stylesheet and assign a prefix to it in order to select the element, however I couldn't find a good advanced tutorial on how to do so (I read the w3cschool one but not complex enough to handle the XML i have on my hand).  Any suggestions?

Comment: @kazuni You can only do this if your XML contains a binding of the `alpha:` prefix to a namespace. I have edited my answer to show what it would look like, and what your stylesheet should do to handle it. Replace the `http://example.com/alpha` namespace URI with the actual one used by your XML.

Comment: I sort of have an idea about what you are saying. A few more follow up questions:
1) http://example.com/alpha has to be a webpage? a directive? what is it actually? does it need to have content?
2) I didnt know the above so i just gave it a random example.com/alpha and when I am processing the XSLT using xsltproc, it prompts "namespace error: Namespace prefix xsl on stylesheet is not defined" which i have defined like your example

Comment: Perhaps let me revise the question with a much closer structure with my example before your answer, thanks!

Comment: @kazuni No, the namespace URI does not have to be an existing web address. I recommend you read about namespaces before moving on, how about you start [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html) and [here](http://www.lenzconsulting.com/namespaces/)?